# Display a row of data

Tags: vba, excel

I need a row of data from an Excel spreadsheet to display when I search for an Organization code.  I can get a cell to show but not the row of information.  There is an error message if the Organization does not match any on the file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
   Option Explicit

    Sub findData()
    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$, MySheet$
    Dim myValue As String

    Txt = InputBox("What Organization do you want to search for?")

    MyPath = "C:\users\DKane\My Documents\"
    MyWB = "EVHC Master Hiring Spreadsheet range find.xlsx"

    MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB

    Set GCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Txt)

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .Value = "Organization"
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Location"
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = GCell.Value
    myValue = GCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = myValue

    .Columns.AutoFit
    .Offset(1, 1).Columns.AutoFit

    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
```

and the header line info (across the top of the sheet):

```
HR Contact (person who can answer questions about this org) 
Region  
Organization (Company.Location Code.Department)
Location in Oracle format
Job Title
PT/FT   
Local Tax Element   
Benefits Code   
Benefits Code Comments (if multiple, how can MHRC determine what benefit code should be used?)  
Mailstop    
Internal Transfer?  
Payroll ID  
Local Tax Element   
Union Code  
Union Code Comments (if multiple, how can MHRC determine when to use which code?)   
Uniform Allowance   
PTO Date    
Drug Screen Provider (e.g. Quest, internal, Concentra)  
Sign-on bonus instructions (including under what circumstances each is used, if multiple)
```

Comment: You can use offset to get the data to, so if a1, is the 1st col, and b2, the 2nd, then offset(a1,0,1...2...3....4) etc.  For the error message, i'd look at using application.worksheetfunction.countif("a:a",txt) being 0..

Answer (score 1):

See this code. From what I read, I think it will give you what you are asking for.

I placed comments in the code itself where I made changes (that may not be obvious), so you can understand.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findData()

    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$, MySheet$
    Dim myValue As String

    Dim wbMain As Workbook
    Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook

    Txt = InputBox("What Organization do you want to search for?")

    MyPath = "C:\users\DKane\My Documents\"
    MyWB = "EVHC Master Hiring Spreadsheet range find.xlsx"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change as needed
    'MySheet = ws.Name

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wbSearch As Workbook
    Set wbSearch = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyWB)

    Set GCell = wbSearch.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(Txt) 'assumes its first worksheet in workbook

    If Not GCell Is Nothing Then 'test if it exists

        'get last column
        Dim lCol As Long
        lCol = wbSearch.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column 'assumes contigous column headers

        'copy headers
        wbSearch.Range(.Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(1, lCol))).Copy ws.Range("A1")

        'copy org rows
        wbSearch.Range(.Range(.Cells(GCell.Row, 1), .Cells(GCell.Row, lCol))).Copy ws.Range("B1")

        ws.Columns.AutoFit

    Else

        MsgBox "Org Not Found"

    End If

    wbSearch.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott I will give this a try

Comment: Seems to be getting stuck on:  lCol = wbSearch.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

Comment: @Dez - can you be more specific about what *getting stuck* means? Is there an error? If so, what is it? Also, you have column headers in row 1 starting with column A, correct?

Comment: when I debug the error is:Run-time error '438':

 Object doesn't support this property or method on this line:lCol = wbSearch.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column